# 'cd' command not working with fabric3

Tags: python, fabric

I'm working with fabric3 (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fabric3) , python 3 port of fabric.

I have the following function:

```
@roles('production')
def dir():
    run('pwd')
    run('ls')
    cd('/home/deploy/mydir')
    run('pwd')
```

output:

```
$ fab dir
[deploy@196.x.x.x] Executing task 'dir'
[deploy@196.x.x.x] run: pwd
[deploy@196.x.x.x] out: /home/deploy
[deploy@196.x.x.x] out:

[deploy@196.x.x.x] run: ls
[deploy@196.x.x.x] out: Env  mysite
[deploy@196.x.x.x] out:

[deploy@196.x.x.x] run: pwd
[deploy@196.x.x.x] out: /home/deploy
[deploy@196.x.x.x] out:
```

Why is it ignoring CD ?

Comment: try `with cd(...): run(...)` - http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/tutorial.html#making-connections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every command works in separated "environment".

`cd()` changes folder but next command starts with new, clear "environment".

But you can use `with`:

```
 with cd("<path>"):   
     run("<command>")
```

See more in Fabric doc: [Context Managers](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/api/core/context_managers.html)

Or you can manually do

```
run("cd <path> && <command>")
```